# Could I say that the peek() method in java.util.stream.Stream should be idempotent

Tags: java-stream, idempotent, peek

My question is related to: [What does idempotent method mean and what are the side effects in case of calling close method of java.lang.AutoCloseable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320115/what-does-idempotent-method-mean-and-what-are-the-side-effects-in-case-of-callin)

As to the method in `java.util.stream.Stream.peek()`, in the book Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 8 Study Guide > chapter 4 Functional programming > Using Streams > Using Common Intermediate Operations, it was stated that *peek() is intended to perform an operation without changing the result*

My **question** is: can I say **in practice, the action in peek(Consumer action) should be idempotent** even though the *stateful* code in `peek()` can compile?

Comment: You can say that the `peek` method should be idempotent. There's no guarantees about the action being called is, though perhaps you're right. It *should* be idempotent, there's' just no guarantee that it will be.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, if you write down the answer I would check :)

Comment: To be honest, I'd rather not. I'm no java expert and your question implies "should" which could be construed as a matter of opinion. If my comment helped you, great! But I'll defer to greater (java) minds to actually post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't because that would imply that the operation can change the final result because an idempotent operation can [mutate the object it operates on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

The following example uses an idempotent operation inside the `peek()` method but **changes the result** (which is not a good practice according to the documentation you pointed out)

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class SomeClass {

    private String state = "some-value";

    public void idempotent() {
        state = "other-value";
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeClass{" +
                "state='" + state + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Idempotent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<SomeClass> collect = Stream.of(new SomeClass(), new SomeClass())
                .peek(SomeClass::idempotent)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

Before the `peek()` operation the stream is composed of `["some-value", "some-value]` and after the `peek()` with an idempotent operation it's composed of `["other-value", "other-value"]`.

Comment: Of course `peek()` can change the state of an object, but I mean that *it should not* The example you gave can compile, but that is no doubt a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc says that it should be [non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), not idempotent, which is not the same thing.

In fact, since it must be non-interfering and can only operate via side-effects, it is likely that it is not idempotent.

The [API note](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) even clearly shows a non-idempotent usage example:

> This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see
>   the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline:
>
> ```
> Stream.of("one", "two", "three", "four")
>     .filter(e -> e.length() > 3)
>     .peek(e -> System.out.println("Filtered value: " + e))
>     .map(String::toUpperCase)
>     .peek(e -> System.out.println("Mapped value: " + e))
>     .collect(Collectors.toList());
> ```

As you know, `System.out.println()` is not idempotent since each call produces a new line of output.